# Invoke doesn't seem to work on ReflectionMethod with empty array?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$loClass    = new ReflectionClass('SampleClass');
$loMethod   = $loClass->getMethod('doSomething');

$loMethod->invoke(array());
```

Let say the class looks like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * Sample Class
 */
class SampleClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Do somehting
     */
    public function doSomething($paParams)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
object(ReflectionException)#181 (7) { ["message":protected]=> string(29) "Non-object passed to Invoke()", ..
```

What I want to do is call a class method from string with parameters as an array (can be empty array)
Can any one help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the method is static you need to pass the object instance where to call this method:

```
$loClass    = new ReflectionClass('SampleClass');
$loMethod   = $loClass->getMethod('doSomething');
$sample     = new SampleClass();

$loMethod->invoke($sample, array());
```

Check the manual page of [`ReflectionMethod::invoke()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.invoke.php)

Comment: Yeah, just found it out myself! Thanks I'll vote you up after a I can (11 min to go)

Comment: :) ... ok, no problem!

Comment: didn't even know php had a reflection class, thanks for sharing.